# Como juntar as duas tabelas nesse caso?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, pivot

Tenho duas tabelas uma "alunos" com a matrícula e inscrição e outra "faz_teste" com as notas dos alunos em determinados testes. Utilizei o comando pivot na tabela "faz_teste" para transformar o nome das provas em coluna e por as notas em linhas, como mostra a query a seguir:

```
SELECT  inscricao,[1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM]
 FROM (
    SELECT inscricao, idteste, nota_num
    FROM [EasyNovo].[dbo].[faz_teste]
    WHERE idteste='1_BIM' OR idteste='2_BIM' OR idteste='3_BIM' OR idteste='4_BIM'
  )tt

PIVOT (SUM(nota_num) 
FOR idteste IN ([1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM]))pvt
```

No resultado dessa query tenho a inscrição e as notas dos alunos em cada prova, como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu preciso por, além da inscrição, o nome. Como fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Ja tentou `SELECT inscricao, idteste, nota_numn, NOME` e no , `PIVOT (SUM(nota_num) , NOME` ..... `SELECT  inscricao,[1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM], NOME` ?

Comment: a Use o JOIN também

Answer (score 1):

Faz o join após ter feito o pivot... da mesma forma que fez um select dentro do from:

```
SELECT 
alunos.nome,
pvt.*
FROM (SELECT  inscricao,[1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM]
 FROM (
    SELECT inscricao, idteste, nota_num
    FROM [EasyNovo].[dbo].[faz_teste]
    WHERE idteste='1_BIM' OR idteste='2_BIM' OR idteste='3_BIM' OR idteste='4_BIM'
  )tt

PIVOT (SUM(nota_num) 
FOR idteste IN ([1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM]))) pvt
INNER JOIN alunos on alunos.inscricao = pvt.inscricao
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer.

```
SELECT  inscricao,[1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM], Nome
 FROM (
    SELECT inscricao, idteste, nota_num, a.Nome
    FROM [EasyNovo].[dbo].[faz_teste] ft
    join [EasyNovo].[dbo].[alunos] a
    on a.idaluno = ft.idaluno
    WHERE idteste='1_BIM' OR idteste='2_BIM' OR idteste='3_BIM' OR idteste='4_BIM'
  )tt

PIVOT (SUM(nota_num) 
FOR idteste IN ([1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM]))pvt
```

veja a ligação da tabela `on a.idaluno = ft.idaluno`

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, mas não funcionou.

Comment: qual erro deu? .

Comment: Aparece só o título das colunas, o conteúdo não.

Comment: você fez a união correta no select "Os IDs "  `on a.idaluno = ft.idaluno`

Comment: Sim, veja como ficou:


 FROM (
    SELECT a.nome, ft.inscricao, ft.idteste, ft.nota_num
    FROM [EasyNovo].[dbo].[faz_teste] ft
    join [EasyNovo].[dbo].[aluno] a
    on a.inscricao = ft.inscricao

 WHERE .....

Comment: Esse select interno está retornando alguma coisa?

Comment: Vou por toda Query pra você ver:

`SELECT  nome, inscricao,[1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM]
 FROM (  SELECT a.nome, ft.inscricao, ft.idteste, ft.nota_num
 FROM [EasyNovo].[dbo].[faz_teste] ft
join [EasyNovo].[dbo].[aluno] a
    on a.inscricao = ft.inscricao
    WHERE idteste='1_BIM' OR idteste='2_BIM' OR idteste='3_BIM' OR idteste='4_BIM'
  )tt

PIVOT (SUM(nota_num) 
FOR idteste IN ([1_BIM],[2_BIM],[3_BIM],[4_BIM]))pvt`

Comment: tente ver o que retorna em . `SELECT a.nome, ft.inscricao, ft.idteste, ft.nota_num FROM [EasyNovo].[dbo].[faz_teste] ft join [EasyNovo].[dbo].[aluno] a on a.inscricao = ft.inscricao WHERE idteste='1_BIM' OR idteste='2_BIM' OR idteste='3_BIM' OR idteste='4_BIM'`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36093/discussion-between-jeferson-leonardo-and-marconcilio-souza).

Comment: Não retorna nada.

Comment: bom ai você vai ter que ver a relação entre essas tabelas .

Comment: Conseguiu alguma coisa?

Comment: Ainda não. Vou voltar a mexer hoje, não tive muito tempo. Se eu conseguir alguma solução posto aqui.

Comment: você tem que rever seu `join` , faça um select que retorne os dados das duas tabelas.